# Multiprocessing in Python script

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have written a Python script that goes through two files, each of above 5 millions of lines. One input contains a series of numbers and the other contains a series of intervals, the script should find the interval that each pair of numbers from the first file belong to and do some calculations depending on the distance between intervals. The script works well but the execution time is too long when the number of lines in the input exceeds 4 millions.

I am not a programmer and I don't have experience with multiprocessing. I was wondering if there is a way in Python to tell the script to work on smaller chunks of the input? It would also be very helpful if you could suggest some beginner guide to multiprocessing. 
I am a beginner in this but I must make my script work for my project. Any guidance regarding this would help me very much. Thanks.

Comment: use a sql database?

Comment: If the script is I/O bound, you might be able to use multithreading which is a little easier than multiprocessing. Regardless, another approach would be to use a different algorithm. For example it might be worthwhile to preprocess the intervals and create a data structure optimized for fast containment checking. Suggest you profile your script and see where it's spending most of it time rather than guessing and using trial and error to find a better solution.

Comment: I see, I think there must exist a more suitable algorithm definitely. I am going to do some checks on the script.

Comment: I recommend you first [profile your script](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) to identify your bottlenecks. Blind and eager optimization is discouraged.